# Template Modification

Tags: templates, thesis

I am new to LaTeX. My questions are not such difficult but for obvious reasons I do need some help.

I found the following template very useful:

```
http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/CUEDThesisPSnPDF.tgz
```

It was supposed to work correctly, however it doesn't load (or it doesn't include in the final pdf file, if you prefer better) three of the sections, namely:
- Contents
- Nomenclature
- References

In addition, for some strange reason, when I try to write my long (three lines) thesis title in the appropriate place of the first page, everything goes messy with the cover page.

Finally, I would like to introduce a "List of Tables" section, just after the "List of Figures" one as well as another one namely "Glossary", just after the end of the "Appendix1".

Comment: It would really be helpful if you could create a minimal document with all the elements mentioned above. That way community members can start with something existing and functional, rather than creating something from scratch that might not conform to your requirements. To be specific, please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/) These are five entirely separate issues, and we strongly prefer to only have one issue per question. So please remove all but one issue from this question and ask the others as separate questions, after checking if these questions already exist on this site. This way, other users looking for help can find solutions more easily. Also don't forget to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) for each question, as Werner remarked.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I do have a working example, but how could I present it in the TEX community? Should I uploaded somewhere?

Comment: @eualin: You should include it in your original question. Once you've pasted it, select the code and press the `{}` button (or use Ctrl + K) to format it as code. If you can't get this to work, paste it anyway, and someone else will edit it and correct the formatting.

Comment: @Werner: The project URL is already there. Is that acceptable for the TEX community? I don't think it would be efficient to copy-paste the whole code here, isn't it?

Comment: @eualin: That is a ZIP-ed document structure that spans multiple chapters - the entire "project" as you call it. We're interested - and would be comfortable digesting - something smaller... Like one chapter, with a couple of sections in it that highlights the problem. That's also why we sometimes request *single* questions with a post, rather than putting everything in one go.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you again for your answer. I did as you asked me: I tried to minimize the initial project to something smaller. Now it consists of about 3 pages. However, I still don't understand how to make it available to you???

Comment: @eualin: [Edit your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/62371/edit) and include it as part of your post. Or, use [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) and share the link. Regardless, if you're unable to figure it out, someone with edit privileges will.